# printjs with vuejs : don't use my css for renderer

Tags: css, vue.js, printjs

I use printjs with vuejs for print a specific page. But he don't accept my css.

My code :

```js
    print() {
        Printjs({
            printable: "print-form",
            type: "html",
            css: '../src/assets/css/print.css',
            scanStyles: false,
        })
    }
```

I have also try :

```
    print() {
        Printjs({
            printable: "print-form",
            type: "html",
            targetStyles: ['*']
        })
    }
```

but with this method, it's all my css and if i have width 100% isn't 100% of print. And if I wan't hidden when it's screen, is hidden for print to.

Comment: Try using `css: "require(../src/assets/css/print.css')"`

Comment: @Amaarockz it doesn't work

Comment: anything on this?